# Issue with images in Django

Tags: python, django

Have an issue with images form in Django.
Upload of images is working correctly and displayed in admin page also right.
But if I want to use this image in my templates or go direct by the link from admin console, receiving 404 error, why?

Django : 2.1.1
Python : 3.6.6

models.py

```
from art.settings import STATICFILES_DIRS
import os

def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join(STATICFILES_DIRS[0], 'collections', filename)

class ArtCollections(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()

class ImagesList(models.Model):
    collection_id = models.ForeignKey(ArtCollections, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True, null=True)
```

From admin console, uploading the file, and its doing in correct folder, exx /static/image.jpg
file is exist :

```
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 438930 Dec  2 /static/image.jpg
```

but still getting 404

P.S. on folder give full grants and for apache also

template ex :

```
{% block content %}
  {{ count }}
  {% for image in collection_images %}
      <img src="{{ image.images }}">
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: can you share your template implementation for the images please?

Comment: @ruddra, done. But im not sure that the reason in template :(

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `url` at the end of images in template:

```
{% block content %}
  {{ count }}
  {% for image in collection_images %}
      <img src="{{ image.images.url }}">
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: unfortunately didnt help:(

Comment: What is you media URL? I think the issue is with media url. Also what is the value you are seeing in image source?